# How to print output inside square bracket in python while using loop

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops

```
from numpy import *

c=array([1,7,3,4,5])

for x in range(len(c)):
    print(c[x]+5, end=",")
```

I want to print it as array how to do it so? Now it is getting printed like this:

`6,12,8,9,10`

Comment: What do you mean by "print it as array"?

Comment: Do you JUST want to print or actually change the array?

Comment: "now it is getting printed like this" How do you want to print it instead? If you do not want the trailing `,`, this is _much_ simpelr without an explicit `for` loop, e.g. `print(','.join(x+5 for x in c))` or `print(*(x+5 for x in c), sep=",")`

Answer (score 2):

Directly add 5 to the numpy array and then print the whole thing.

```
import numpy as np
c = np.array([1,7,3,4,5])
print(c+5)
```

```
[ 6 12  8  9 10]
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for

```
l = [1, 7, 3, 4, 5]
print([x + 5 for x in l])
```

which will print

```
[6, 12, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by 'as an array', but you can try

```
print('[' + ''.join([str(elt + 5) for elt in c) + ']')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> c = np.array([1,7,3,4,5])
>>> print(c)
[1, 7, 3, 4, 5]
>>> c5 = c+5
>>> print(c5)
[ 6, 12,  8,  9, 10]
```